# Peer to Peer with NAT Traversal using WCF at Runtime

Tags: wcf, p2p, nat-traversal

As the title says, is it possible to establish P2P connection between two systems which can get past NAT's. These two programs are connected to a WCF Service that identifies certain connected clients to other connected clients. The programs then receive information about each other. This is where I'm not sure. How can these two programs that know about each other connect directly to each other so they can communicated without sending any information via the service. I'm not sure if you can do this in WCF or not, but if not, are there any other solutions. Any source code would be great.

Comment: Thats Here Hole Punching Technique Comes in to the Picture.Try to Implement UDp Hoile PUnching There.http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/26d08301-0aac-4549-ae4d-882d164d2a4e/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats Here Hole Punching Technique Comes in to the Picture.Try to Implement UDp Hole PUnching There.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/26d08301-0aac-4549-ae4d-882d164d2a4e/

http://www.brynosaurus.com/pub/net/p2pnat/

Comment: cheers man, that looks great. do you know of any existing c# implementations of it, or do i have to write my own one?

Comment: NAT Can Traversed using UPnP as well http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/upnpnattraversal.aspx

Comment: Well, im going to work on a library to help me do it automatically, and i was going to use upnp as the first try, then this, cheers anyway though